# What could be cause of error "malloc: *** error for object 0x7b: pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: c, malloc, free, runtime-error

I am writing this program for a class. This program is a simple parenthesis checker application using stacks. In this case, I have used static arrays to implement the stack data structure. The program builds fine but I run into this runtime error and thus far have not been able to see where the problem could be stemming from.

Here is little information that I do understand that the problem could be due to trying to free memory that was not allocated using malloc. But in the following code, I don't see where this could be happening.

The following is the interface implementation code for stack using a static array. I have also added the stack interface code to add characters on the stack and the driver program to test the routines.

```
#include "stack.h"
#include "stdlib.h" /* malloc, free */
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAXSTACKSIZE 10

struct stack_record {
  generic_ptr base[MAXSTACKSIZE];
  generic_ptr * top;
};

unsigned int num_elements(stack * const p_S)
{
  unsigned int numels = ((*p_S)->top - (*p_S)->base);
  /*  return ((*p_S)->top - (*p_S)->base); */
  printf("number of elements in the stack is: %u\n", numels);
  return numels;
}
status init_stack(stack * const p_S)
{
  stack_record * record = (stack_record *)malloc(sizeof(stack_record));
  if(record == NULL) {
    return ERROR;
  }
  record->top = record->base;
  *p_S = record;
  return OK;
}
bool empty_stack(stack * const p_S)
{
  if(num_elements(p_S) == 0)
    {
      printf("stack is EMPTY!\n");
      return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("stack NOT Empty!\n");
      return FALSE;
    }
}
status push(stack * const p_S, generic_ptr const data)
{
  if (num_elements(p_S) == MAXSTACKSIZE)
    return ERROR;

  *( (*p_S)->top ) = data;
  (*p_S)->top++;
   return OK;
}

status pop(stack * const p_S, generic_ptr * const p_data)
{
  if (empty_stack(p_S) == TRUE)
    return ERROR;
  *p_data = *((*p_S)->top);
  (*p_S)->top--;
  /*  ((*p_S)->top)--; */
  return OK;
}

status top(stack *const p_S, generic_ptr * const p_data)
{
   if (pop(p_S, p_data) == ERROR)
    return ERROR;

  return push(p_S, *p_data);
}

void destroy_stack(stack * const p_S, void (* const p_func_f)())
{
  if ((p_func_f) != NULL) {
    generic_ptr * curr;    
    for(curr = (*p_S)->top;
    curr != (*p_S)->base;
    ++curr)
          (*p_func_f)(*curr);
  }
  free(*p_S); /*free the dynamically allocated memory on the heap */
  *p_S = NULL;
 }
```

Following are the stack interface routines for characters:

```
/*************************************************************************/
/* adapted from Esakov and Weiss, Section 5.2                            */
/*************************************************************************/

#include "char_stack.h"
#include "stdlib.h" /* malloc */
#include "stdio.h"
#define DEBUG 1 

status push_char(stack * const p_S, char const c)
{
  /*
   *     Push the character c onto the stack.
   */
  char * p_c = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

  if(p_c == NULL)
    return ERROR;
  *p_c = c;

  if(DEBUG)
  /* Debug code: begin */
  {
    printf("Character to PUSH on the stack: %c\n", *p_c);
  }
  /* Debug code: end */

  if (push(p_S, (generic_ptr)p_c) == ERROR) {
    if(DEBUG)
      printf("char_stack: push_char: failed to push the character on the stack!\n");
    free(p_c);
    return ERROR;
  }
  return OK;
}

status pop_char(stack * const p_S, char * const p_c)
{
  /*
   *     Pop the stack. Return the character in p_c.
   */

  generic_ptr p_data;

  if( pop(p_S, &p_data) == ERROR)
    return ERROR;

  *p_c = *((char*)p_data);

  if(DEBUG)
  /*Debug code: begin */
printf("char_stack.c::pop_char: Character to POP on the stack: %c\n", *p_c);

  /*Debug code: end */

   free(p_data);
   return OK;
}

status top_char(stack * const p_S, char * const p_c)
{
  /*
   *     Return the top character from the stack in p_c
   */
  generic_ptr p_data;

  if (top(p_S, &p_data) == ERROR)
    return ERROR;

  *p_c = *((char *)p_data); 
  return OK;
}
```

Driver program for the application:

```
/**************************************************************************/
/* adapted from Esakov and Weiss, Section 5.2                             */
/**************************************************************************/

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "char_stack.h"

char matching_symbol(char const c)
{
  switch(c) {
    case '(': return ')';
    case ')': return '(';
    case '}': return '{';
    case '{': return '}';
    case '[': return ']';
    case ']': return '[';
  }
  return 0;
}

status consume_char(stack * const p_S, char input)
{
  switch (input) {
    case '(':
    case '{':  
    case '[':
      return push_char(p_S, input); 
    case ')':
    case '}':
    case ']':
      { 
        char c;    
        if (pop_char(p_S, &c) == ERROR || c != matching_symbol(input)) { 
          return ERROR;
        } else {
          return OK;
        }
      }
    default:
      return OK; 
  }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

  if (argc == 1) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  {
    stack S;

    init_stack(&S);

    {
      char *ptr;
      for (ptr = argv[1];
           *ptr != '\0' && consume_char(&S, *ptr) == OK;
           ++ptr); 
      if (*ptr == '\0' && empty_stack(&S)) { 

    destroy_stack(&S,free);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      } else {
    destroy_stack(&S,free);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }  

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
}
```

I would like to add that in the driver program, I have narrowed that the call to destroy stack is what triggers this issue. But I have reviewed this code and believe this code is fine and the problem is elsewhere.

[Edit 1]: For completeness, I have appended the driver code where these functions are being called. 
[Edit 2]: Added the stack interface routines for characters.

Comment: I only see function definitions.  Where are the functions being called?

Comment: It seems that you are freeing `p_S`, which is a `const` pointer and passed as a function argument.  This must also be freed elsewhere in the programme, e.g. where it was actually defined, or when the scope has ended.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am actually dereferencing p_S to obtain the pointer that was returned by malloc. This is what I am passing to free to free up the block of memory allocated on the heap for stack_record. stack_record contains the static array that is being used to store pointers to char's.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you passed the value 0x7b to `free`. Such a small number will never be the address of a block of memory returned from `malloc`. So, roughly, there are three possibilities:

1. You have a completely uninitialized pointer that happens to have ended up with 0x7b in it, and you are passing it to `free`.
2. You have started with a pointer containing 0, incremented it by 0x7b, and passed that to `free`.
3. You have some more creative memory corruption error that has replaced a valid pointer value with 0x7b.

The fastest way out is to run your program under valgrind and let it tell you where all this is happening. You can also put breakpoints here and there in gdb and see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `main` function you're passing `free` as a function pointer as the second argument to `destroy_stack`.  The point of this is to `free` all of the data elements that are currently on the stack (if there are any left).  However, you are only allowed to free this memory if the `push` function used `malloc` to allocate memory when items were added to the stack.

In the given implementation, the stack doesn't have the responsibility of allocating memory for the items, so it probably shouldn't be trying to free that memory.  In either case, the place to look for a discrepancy is probably in the function `push_char`:

It looks like `push_char` is trying to push a simple '{' character (BTW this is `0x7B`), instead of a pointer to some memory created by `malloc` as expected by the stack.

**Update**

Scratch what I said about `push_char` in the previous paragraph - the problem is in `destroy_stack`, this line:

```
(*p_func_f)(*curr);    /* Incorrect */
```

`curr` is a pointer to some memory allocated for a single character (allocated by `push_char`), and `*p_func_f` is the `free()` function.  Can you see the problem?

It is an error to dereference `curr` when passing it into `*p_func_f`.  Instead, just pass the raw pointer:

```
(*p_func_f)(curr);     /* Correct */
```

The key to discovering this was the same as I mentioned above: the "memory address" `0x7b` is in fact the character '{', which is the data stored on the stack -- this strongly suggested that the `free` function was receiving raw data rather than the pointer to that data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I checked the code and indeed push_char() which is the interface function for this application (parenthesis checker program) does use malloc and then pushes the pointer on the stack. So, I am inclined to rule this option out. I'll post rest of the code as part of the follow-up.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The actual problem was that I was attempting to free the pointer stored at the "top". This slot was the next place where a new item **would** be pushed. It was wrong to dereference this location since it was empty! Hence, the nasty error. I fixed it by rewriting the loop so my "curr" decrements and free's the pointers until the first pointer at (*p_S)->base is reached.

Comment: Ah I see.  I'm glad you figured it out.  PS the code in the for loop you have above actually _increments_ the `curr` pointer from `top` instead of decrementing it, though I'm sure you have all the information you need to work out any other issues you may have.